# How can I pass data through a Navigation Link with FetchedResults and CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to pass FetchResult Data from one screen to another, through a Navigation Link in a ScrollView.

When I try to call the passed data in the DetailView screen, I get the following error:
`Instance member "" cannoth be used on type "SavedPoem"`

Code below - Saved Poem List

```
import SwiftUI

struct SavedPoemList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems : FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack{
                Text("Your Saved Poems")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                    
                Spacer()
                    
                    
            }.padding(.bottom)
            .padding(.trailing)
            .padding(.leading)
               
            ScrollView {
                    
                ForEach(savedpoems, id:\.title) {SavedPoem in
                   
                    NavigationLink (destination: DetailViewSaved()){
                      
                        ZStack {
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 40, height: 70)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .padding([.horizontal], 20)
//                                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
                                                        
                            HStack {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.title ?? "")")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 3)
                                        
                                    
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                                .padding(.trailing)
                                Spacer()
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }.padding(.bottom,10)
                        
                    }
                    
                }.onDelete(perform: self.remove)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Saved Poems")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
                    

            }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        
    }
        func remove(at offsets : IndexSet) {
            for index in offsets {
                let delete = savedpoems[index]
                self.moc.delete(delete)
            }
            try? self.moc.save()
        }
}
```

and Code for the Detail View

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailViewSaved: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems : FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    @State private var saved : Bool = false
    
    var currentDate = Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(600), style: .date)
    
    var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
                
                HStack{
                    
//                    NavigationLink( destination: HomeView())
//                    {
//
//                        Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
//                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
//                            .foregroundColor(.black)
//                    }
                    
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                    Button(action:
                            {
//                            self.moc.delete(delete)
                            
                            try? self.moc.save()
     
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: saved ? "bookmark.fill": "bookmark")
                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                } 
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        HStack{
                            
                            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                
                                Text("Today's Poem, \(currentDate)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                                    
                                    
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.title ?? "")")
//                                        .font(.largeTitle)
//                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
//                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
//                                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
//                                        .lineSpacing(0)
                                    
//                                    Text("BY "+poem.author.uppercased())
                                    Text("BY \(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
//                                        .font(.subheadline)
//                                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
//                                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("\(SavedPoem.lines ?? "")")
//                                            .font(.body)
//                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
//                                            .padding(.bottom)
//                                            .lineSpacing(5)
//
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    
                                    
               
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            .padding()
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }

        }
```

Am I missing anything? How can I resolve this issue, and pass the data from the Fetchedresults in the list view to the detailed screen?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED CODE FOR REPLY**

SavedPoemList:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SavedPoemList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems : FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack{
                Text("Your Saved Poems")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                    
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Edit")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                    
            }.padding(.bottom)
            .padding(.trailing)
            .padding(.leading)
               
            ScrollView {
                    
                ForEach(savedpoems, id:\.title) {SavedPoem in
                   
                    NavigationLink (destination: DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem)){
                      
                        ZStack {
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 40, height: 70)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                                .padding([.horizontal], 20)
//                                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10)
                                                        
                            HStack {
                                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.title ?? "")")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 3)
                                        
                                    
                                    Text("\(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                                .padding(.trailing)
                                Spacer()
                                
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }.padding(.bottom,10)
                        
                    }
                    
                }.onDelete(perform: self.remove)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Saved Poems")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
                    

            }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        
    }
        func remove(at offsets : IndexSet) {
            for index in offsets {
                let delete = savedpoems[index]
                self.moc.delete(delete)
            }
            try? self.moc.save()
        }
}
```

DetailView

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailViewSaved: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPoem()
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: SavedPoem.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var savedpoems : FetchedResults<SavedPoem>
    
    @State private var saved : Bool = false
    
    var savedPoem : SavedPoem
    
    var currentDate = Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(600), style: .date)
    
    var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
                
                HStack{
                    
//                    NavigationLink( destination: HomeView())
//                    {
//
//                        Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
//                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
//                            .foregroundColor(.black)
//                    }
                    
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                    Button(action:
                            {
//                            self.moc.delete(delete)
                            
                            try? self.moc.save()
     
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: saved ? "bookmark.fill": "bookmark")
                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .heavy))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                } 
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        HStack{
                            
                            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                
//                                Text("Today's Poem, \(currentDate)")
//                                    .font(.subheadline)
//                                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
//                                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
//                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                                    
                                    
                                    Text("\(savedPoem.title ?? "")")
//                                        .font(.largeTitle)
//                                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
//                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
//                                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
//                                        .lineSpacing(0)
                                    
//                                    Text("BY "+poem.author.uppercased())
//                                    Text("BY \(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
//                                        .font(.subheadline)
//                                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
//                                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    
//                                    HStack {
//                                        Text("\(SavedPoem.lines ?? "")")
//                                            .font(.body)
//                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
//                                            .padding(.bottom)
//                                            .lineSpacing(5)
//
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    
                                    
               
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            .padding()
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }

        }

   struct DetailViewSaved_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example with your case :

**SavedPoemList** : Pass an item from your array to your `Detail View` like that :

```
NavigationLink (destination: DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem)){
            VStack{
                Text("Your row view")
            }
}
```

and to receive it in your `Detail View` :

```
struct DetailViewSaved: View {
    var savedPoem : SavedPoem
    var body: some View {
        Text("Your view")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ouail. I tried your suggestion and got the following errors:
- In SavedPoemList, at the ForEach: "Generic parameters "Content" could not be inferred"
- In  Detail View, when declaring the variable: "Expected member name call after type name
- In Detail View, when calling the variable: Text("\(savedPoem.title ?? "")"), "Instance member "title" cannot be used on type "Save Poem "

Comment: @Simbeul can you please edit your question with the error that you got

Comment: Done thanks! I listed the errors in the comment above.

Comment: EDIT: I made a typo and had var savedPoem = SavedPoem instead of var savedPoem : SavedPoem... my bad!

Comment: There is one error remaining: in my struct DetailViewSaved_Previews, it throws: Missing Argument for parameter "SavedPoem" in call... what should I add?

Comment: @Simbeul  the  same way that you are calling it in the navigation link : `DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem)` , but here you need to create a SavedPoem object

Comment: Thanks, @Ouail. I am getting "Cannot convert value of type "SavedPoem.Type" to expected argument type "SavedPoem".

Comment: @Simbeul try `DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem())`